# How to customize MkDocs Material CSS?

Tags: github-pages, mkdocs, mkdocs-material

I have GH pages with MkDocs set up, using the Material theme. For whatever reason, I'm unable to customize the CSS as described in the documentation.

I have nothing to go by troubleshooting-wise as I get no errors when running mkdocs locally. The custom CSS is just ignored as far as I can tell.

I've set up extra.css file to overwrite styling but whatever I configure doesn't work.

Do I need to update/override the CSS *variables* the Material theme uses?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: same [indentation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75244566/2718933) as @VRehnberg had back in Jan.

List of extra CSS needs to be defined on the 'root' level of `mkdocs.yml` and **not** indented.